# Can not change the frame of an IBOutlet property

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

Say, I have a ViewController and I set a property :

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
```

In the xib file of the Controller, I add a UIView On the default UIView and set its frame as {0, 0, 320, 568}. And I connect it with the property contentView.

In the viewDidLoad method I do:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 300);
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];   //frame print to be {0, 20, 320, 300}
}
```

The problem is that the frame of the contentView presents to be  {0, 0, 320, 568} on the iphone. But I print out the frame to be what I set in the viewDidLoad method.

How did this happen? Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using autolayout?

If yes, you can not change the frame.

Either turn off auto layout, or use constraints to change the size of your view. Hope this helps.